# How can one make a fixed width column on the right, which works in IE 9 in normal and compatibility mode?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, ie8-compatibility-mode

Consider the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; width:100%">
    <input type="button" style="width:20px;float:right;" value="a" />
    <div style="padding-right:35px;">
            <input type="text" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the correct layout, and how it looks in IE 9 in normal mode.  If you stretch the browser, the button remains on the right of the input box, and the input box stretches accordingly.

[image: IE 9 Normal]

This is how it looks in IE 9 in compatibility mode.  As you can see, the input box jumps onto the next line:

[image: IE 9 Compatibility Mode]

So, is there a way to fix this, so that it works regardless of whether or not compatibility mode is set?

Obviously I'm looking for a solution with minimal hackiness :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason the button should be before the textbox?

Comment: Yip... swap them around and the button jumps onto the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this HTML:

```
<div class="search"><input name="btn" type="button" value="a" /><span><input type="text" name="search_input" /></span></div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.search > span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.search input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
}
.search input[type=button] {
  float: right;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle to test it out for yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/KVhUC/

I was able to get it to work with FF, IE9 (with/without compatibility mode)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Cytkx/4/

```
<div style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin;">
    <input type="button" style="width:20px;float:right;overflow:hidden;" value="a" />
    <div style="overflow:hidden;padding-right:10px;">
        <input type="text" style="display:block;width:100%;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe this is close to what you're looking for. Note this may not be backwards compatible.

Comment: And, obviously, it would be better to not use inline styles.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I'm looking for.  The right of the input box is hidden under the button.

Comment: @LostHobbit just add some padding/margin to the input box's wrapping element.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using `<Table> </Table>` instead of `Div`. They are better containers compared with divs.

Comment: Many web developers these days don't believe in using <table> tags unless working with tabular data.  I'll wait to see if there are any other suggestions.

Comment: -1 -- you can apply table-like display handling to divs with CSS, there's no reason to use the actual table tags for anything except... tables of data.